# npm WARN tarball tarball data for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.10.0 seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time

Tags: react-native

```
E:\React native\Demo>npm install -g expo-cli
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.10.0 (sha512-+9Mjvs9m15Meexp00A2JDXLfQHwcgua1dI0ldqVboHblzTACTMvXrfHmewxBoIBLZ45c1lLuIHD7+3UAnBHVCA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.10.0 (sha512-Ry9gHhDIPjSnP5lvtUcR7LoE5vU2Ngn893B22PYEk1RuwJG5m7ezKSGyXjs3W1WVUvPW/2+ikF1YjrNyPAIrqQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
[            ......] \ extract:rxjs: WARN tarball tarball data for @e**strong text**
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux` first with

```
npm i -g @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux
```

before installing `expo-cli` globally via `npm`.

This worked for me. Hope this helps others who are facing the same issue.